# Ubuntu accessing the Virtual BOX DSN

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, dsn

I have Ubuntu 12.04 Installed on my System and have installed Virtual box  4.1.12. and Having Windows7 running in my VBOX (Guest Addition Installed).

Now I have crated the DSN on VWin7 Instance which allows to MS Access DB. and I need to access that DSN  on my virtual system.

Does it need any special configuration to have this access ?? Already can access share folder and Net over VBOX Win7 Instance

Can any one figure out what configuration or what I missing ?

Thank You

Comment: What have you tried? Did you get an error message when you tried to connect to the DB?

Comment: actually i can not access Virtual Machine IP from the my host Ubuntu system,

Comment: Then you need to set up host-only networking first. See the VBox docs for that.

Comment: the network setup should be done as mentioned in [Ubuntu 10 on Virtual box as server for a windows 7 host](http://superuser.com/q/175984)